# Fitting (multlple) linear models by group in R

Tags: r, regression

I'm trying to (somewhat) elegantly fit 3 models (linear, exponential and quadratic) to a dataset with classes/factors and save p-values and R2 for each model and class/factor.  Simple dataset with 3 variables: x,y, and class.  What I can't figure out is how to force each of the 3 models to fit to each of the 3 classes.  What I have now fits each model to the complete dataset.  The next question is how I then output p-values & R2 to a table, for each model+class

My code looks like:

```
set.seed(100)
library(plyr)  
#create datast
nit <- within(data.frame(x = 3:32),
                 {
                   class <- rep(1:3, each = 10)
                   y <- 0.5 * x* (1:10) + rnorm(30)
                   class <- factor(class)                 # convert to a factor
                 }
                 )
x2<-nit$x*nit$x #for quadratic model
forms<- paste(c("y ~ x", "y ~ x+x2", "log(y) ~ x"), sep = "") # create 3 models
names(forms) <- paste("Model", LETTERS[1:length(forms)])
models <- llply(forms, lm, data = nit)
models                # shows coefficients for each of the 3 models
```

Comment: This is an R programming question that would almost certainly get a better response on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of ways to do this, but I liked how the names came out of nested `lapply` calls better than my `mapply` or `do` (from package *dplyr*) solutions even though the code looks a bit complicated.  The names made it easier to tell the models apart (which `forms` and `class` combination each list element represented).

In this solution, it is important to actually add `x2` to the `nit` dataset.

```
nit$x2 = nit$x*nit$x
models = lapply(forms, 
            function(x) {
                lapply(levels(nit$class), 
                    function(y) {lm(x, data = nit[nit$class == y,])} )
})
```

The output is a lists of lists, though, so I had to flatten this into a single list using `unlist` with `recursive = FALSE`.

```
models2 = unlist(models, recursive = FALSE)
```

Now you can easily pull out elements you want from the `summary` of each model.  For example, here is how you might pull at the R-squared for each model:

```
lapply(models2, function(x) summary(x)$r.squared)
```

Or if you want a vector instead of a list:

```
unlist(lapply(models2, function(x) summary(x)$r.squared))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider to jump into linear and quadratic discrimination analyis, LDA and QDA.
This guide provides an easy introduction

http://tgmstat.wordpress.com/2014/01/15/computing-and-visualizing-lda-in-r/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this? You can probably adapt it to do exactly what you want.

```
modsumm <- llply(models, summary)
ldply(modsumm, function(x) data.frame(term = row.names(x$coefficients),
                                      x$coefficients,
                                      R.sq = x$r.squared))

      .id        term     Estimate  Std..Error    t.value     Pr...t..      R.sq
1 Model A (Intercept) -12.60545292 11.37539598 -1.1081331 2.772327e-01 0.5912020
2 Model A           x   3.70767525  0.58265177  6.3634498 6.921738e-07 0.5912020
3 Model B (Intercept)  16.74908684 20.10241672  0.8331877 4.120490e-01 0.6325661
4 Model B           x  -0.73357356  2.60879262 -0.2811927 7.807063e-01 0.6325661
5 Model B          x2   0.12689282  0.07278352  1.7434279 9.263740e-02 0.6325661
6 Model C (Intercept)   1.79394266  0.32323588  5.5499490 6.184167e-06 0.5541830
7 Model C           x   0.09767635  0.01655626  5.8996644 2.398030e-06 0.5541830
```

Or, if you just want the p-value from the F statistic and the R squared

```
 ldply(modsumm, function(x) data.frame(F.p.val = pf(x$fstatistic[1],
                                                    x$fstatistic[2],
                                                    x$fstatistic[3],
                                                    lower.tail = F),
                                       R.sq = x$r.squared))

      .id      F.p.val      R.sq
1 Model A 6.921738e-07 0.5912020
2 Model B 1.348711e-06 0.6325661
3 Model C 2.398030e-06 0.5541830
```